# How to extract transaction hash out of XDR using Java Script?

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, stellar-sdk, xdr

iam having an XDR i want to know the transaction hash before i submit that to stellar. i did this in GO by unmarshal the XDR and used the builder to retrieve the hash. Is there nay way that i can do it in JS.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a `transaction` you have, and not a `transaction envelope`, then the transaction hash is formed using the XDR directly.

```
const envelopeType = StellarSdk.xdr.EnvelopeType.envelopeTypeTx().toXDR();
const signatureBase = Buffer.concat([networkId, envelopeType, txXDR])
const transactionHash = StellarSdk.hash(signatureBase);
```